# How can I debug Ubuntu's kernel?

Tags: kernel, gdb

How can I debug Ubuntu's kernel? Are there any debug symbols available, or should I recompile the kernel with debug info?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The kernel team have a wonderful [wiki page](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/KernelTeam).

it has a kernel debugging page where you can find :

- Debugging Scenarios
- Debugging Guides
- Debugging Tools/Information

To determine which guides are relevant to your problem see the [Kernel/Debugging/Symptom](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/Debugging/Symptom) based debugging guide .

Comment: -1 , you don't actually answer the question "Are there any debug symbols available, or should I recompile the kernel with debug info?". Which of the guides on the [wiki page](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/KernelTeam) is for generic Kernel debugging with common tools like `perf`?

Answer (score 2):

Useful information can be found on this page

https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/Systemtap

Specifically

```
sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ddebs.list << EOF
deb http://ddebs.ubuntu.com/ precise          main restricted universe multiverse
deb http://ddebs.ubuntu.com/ precise-security main restricted universe multiverse
deb http://ddebs.ubuntu.com/ precise-updates  main restricted universe multiverse
deb http://ddebs.ubuntu.com/ precise-proposed main restricted universe multiverse
EOF

sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys ECDCAD72428D7C01
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install linux-image-$(uname -r)-dbgsym
```

Now I just need to figure out the Debian equivalent.